# issue adding JAVA_HOME environment variable to hadoop-env,sh file using sed

Tags: hadoop, sed, environment-variables

When I run the command:

```
sed -i "\$aexport JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin" $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
```

I get the error:

> sed: can't read /usr/share/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
>   no such file or directory

I verified the directory and file exist.  `$HADOOP_HOME=/usr/share/hadoop`

Do you know what the issue is?  I have already searched StackOverflow and google and did not find a solution.

Comment: Are you using Cygwin? You can export JAVA_HOME separately

Answer (score 1):

So, I will tackle with this problem by doing following checks as a starting point:

I- Check the value of variable named `$HADOOP_HOME` I believe which you already checked it, you could print it once by doing `echo "$HADOOP_HOME"`, if this is good do following then.

II- Do a `ls -ld $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` and see if file is present there or not.

III- Then try to change you sed command to following once:

```
sed -i "\$aexport JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin" "$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh"
```

Let us know how it goes then.

Comment: Here are the responses to items 1-3:  1.  /usr/share/hadoop   2.  -rw-r--r-- 1 gary gary  16080 Dec   8  11:42 /usr/share/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh    3.  sed: can't read /usr/share/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: No such file or directory